# Logging from inside a repository in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm tracing a weird error in a Symfony 2 app and I'd like to know if there's a way to print log messages from a Repository PHP file. For example:

```
class OrderEntityRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
    * 
    * @param mixed $filter
    * @return type
    */ 
    public function findByCriteria($filter) {
        [...]

        /* I'D LIKE TO LOG SOME VARIABLES FROM HERE */
    }
}
```

I've tried using `error_log()` but nothing happens.

Is this possible? Thanks in advance,

Comment: I'm not sure, but you would like to try with PHPUnit

Comment: Setup a logger service for the repository and then call it (`$this->logger->info($my, $vars)`). Or use `VarDumper`'s `dump()`. If you have `print_r` or whatnot and nothing's happening, likely it's not getting called.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible but it's usually not a good practice. The good thing to do is to send back the Repository result to your Controller or Service and you log from them an error or something else.

But if you still want to do it, Repository are like services (when you implements `ServiceEntityRepository` [see this slide for more information](http://talks.nekland.fr/Doctrine/#/18)). If you want to log something specific inside you have to inject the LoggerInterface into your Repository configuration (like you do with service).

In your service.yml (or xml) if you don't use autowire:

```
Your\Repository:
    arguments: ['@logger']
```

In your repository class:

```php
/**
 * @var LoggerInterface
 */
protected $logger;


public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
{
    $this->logger = $logger;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I've modified the files `Resources/config/service.yml` and the repository class file following your instructions, and I get this error:  `Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Master\StoreBundle\Entity\Repository\OrderEntityRepository::__construct() must be an instance of Master\StoreBundle\Entity\Repository\LoggerInterface, instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager given`. Do I have to change anything else to make it work?

Comment: @Fel Basic problem is that original question did not make it clear that you were using Doctrine's repository.  So this answer is less that useful.  Just lookup how to use a factory to create the repository service and how to use setters to inject the logger.

Comment: @Cerad I've read the comment you left for my post but you decided to delete it but I am very much interested in what you had to say to my question above. It is because if I miss something I would like to know. Thanks

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. I couldn't make it work but I found a workaround using `echo` and printing what I need to the HTML output. It doesn't solve the question, but I'll keep on investigating and I'll update it when I find something relevant.

Answer (score 0):

On symfony 3.8 I have

```
class BlahRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{

    /* @var ContainerInterface $container */
    private $container;

    /* @var LoggerInterface $logger */
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry, ContainerInterface $container, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Blah::class);
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }
}
```

and I am able to use `$this->logger->info("text")`

I think the trick may be extending `ServiceEntityRepository`

Answer (score 0):

In order to use dependency injection for Doctrine entity repositories, you can create a custom RepositoryFactory.
Tested on Symfony 3.4.

```php
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Doctrine;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Configuration;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Repository\DefaultRepositoryFactory;
use Doctrine\ORM\Repository\RepositoryFactory as RepositoryFactoryInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerAwareInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class RepositoryFactory implements RepositoryFactoryInterface, LoggerAwareInterface
{
    /** @var DefaultRepositoryFactory */
    protected $defaultRepositoryFactory;

    /** @var LoggerInterface */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * @required (for autowiring)
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger (Monolog will be the default one)
     */
    public function setLogger(LoggerInterface $logger): void
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @see Configuration::getRepositoryFactory()
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->defaultRepositoryFactory = new DefaultRepositoryFactory();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the repository for an entity class.
     *
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
     * @param string $entityName The name of the entity.
     * @return ObjectRepository
     */
    public function getRepository(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, $entityName): ObjectRepository
    {
        $repository = $this->defaultRepositoryFactory->getRepository($entityManager, $entityName);

        if ($repository instanceof LoggerAwareInterface && $this->logger !== null) {
            $repository->setLogger($this->logger);
        }

        return $repository;
    }
}
```

Declare it in Doctrine configuration.

```
# app/config.yml
doctrine:
    # ...
    orm:
        repository_factory: AppBundle\Doctrine\RepositoryFactory
```

And finally, make your repository class implement `LoggerAwareInterface`.

```php
class OrderEntityRepository extends EntityRepository implements LoggerAwareInterface
{
    /** @var LoggerInterface */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function setLogger(LoggerInterface $logger): void
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $filter
     * @return type
     */
    public function findByCriteria($filter) {
        //[...]
        $this->logger->alert('message');
    }
}
```

You can also make a `LoggerAwareTrait` trait to spare yourself some code duplication.